# Как задать формат отображения ячейки qtablewidget при вводе

Tags: c++, qt5

Нужно заполнить таблицу из объекта Json. Имеем:

```
{ 
    "BTC_BCN": { 
        "id" : 7,
        "last" : "0.00000031",
        "lowestAsk" : "0.00000031",
        "highestBid" : "0.00000030",
        "percentChange" : "0.00000000",
        "baseVolume" : "6.72899890",
        "quoteVolume" : "21962419.02871397",
        "isFrozen" : "0",
        "high24hr" : "0.00000031",
        "low24hr" : "0.00000030"
    }
}
```

PS: Вопрос именно "Как задать формат ячейки, переведя из строки в число, чтобы видеть "длинные" числа до 8 знаков после запятой?"

```
for(auto iter2 = jv.begin(); iter2 != jv.end(); ++iter2)
{
    ptwi = new QTableWidgetItem();
    const auto value  = iter2.value(); 
    if (iter2.value().isString() ) 
    {
        auto value1 = QVariant( value.toString() );
        ptwi->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value1);
    } 
    else 
    {
        auto value1 = QVariant( value.toDouble() );
        ptwi->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value1);
    }
    ui->tableWidgetPair->setItem(row2, col2, ptwi);
    col2++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, вот тут у вас что-то непонятное, так работать не должно:

```
QString::number(iter2.value().toDouble()) .arg(row2).arg(col2)
```

Формат ячейки задать конечно можно, ведь на самом деле `QTableWidgetItem` хранит значение в `QVariant`. И именно в `QVariant` значения передаются в представление для отрисовки. И да, представление обрабатывает код типа данных из `QVariant` чтобы изобразить правильный контрол когда пользователь соберется редактировать поле.

У вас же, вся описанная мною изкоробочная красота не работает, потому что вы инициализируете тип значения как строку. Чтобы тип значения определялся нужно устанавливать значение функцией [QTableWidgetItem::setData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData). Короче надо вот так делать:

```
 for(auto iter2 = jv.begin();iter2!=jv.end(); ++iter2)
 {
     ptwi = new QTableWidgetItem();
     const auto value  = iter2.value();
     const auto value1 = QVariant(value.toDouble());   // приводим к нужному типу
     const auto value2 = qvariant_cast<double>(value); // а можно и так
     ptwi->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value1);
     ui->tableWidgetPair->setItem(row2,col2,ptwi);
     col2++;
 }
```

А вот как узнать тип значение в json'е с этим сложнее. Вообще, обычно ПО разрабатывается так, что типы известны до того как начинается работа с данными. В вашем случае, если набор типов ограничен и известен (например только целые и вещественные), можно попробовать выполнять разбор одновременно для всех типов и потом выбирать из тех где не было ошибок разбора. Может есть библиотеки для json'а которые умеют "угадывать" тип данных. Qt так не умеет насколько я помню.

Comment: Немного не то спрашивал. Пока работает вариант   if (iter2.value().isString()){
                auto value1 = QVariant(value.toString());
                ptwi->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value1);
            }else{
                auto value1 = QVariant(value.toDouble());
                ptwi->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value1);

Comment: спасибо. определять научился, но вопрос остался)

Answer (score 1):

Читаем json (я сократил ваш для удобства):

```
QJsonParseError error;
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(QString(
    "{ \"BTC_BCN\": { \"id\" : \"7\", \"last\" : \"0.00000031\" }}").toUtf8(), &error);

if( doc.isObject() )
{
    QJsonObject object = doc.object();

    for(const QString& key: object.keys())
    {
        qDebug() << key; // "BTC_BCN"
        QJsonValue value = object.value(key);
        if( value.type() == QJsonValue::Object )
        {
            QJsonObject v = value.toObject();
            for(const QString& k: v.keys())
            {
                qDebug() << k << v.value(k);
                // "id"   QJsonValue(string, "7")
                // "last" QJsonValue(string, "0.00000031")
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
} else
{
    // Какая-то ошибка при парсинге json
    qDebug() << error.errorString();
}
```

В процессе чтения заполняем таблицу, или дерево, или что-то еще )